# How does List<T> copy constructor function with ReadOnly lists?

Tags: c#, .net, list, readonly-collection

The MSDN article doesn't really explain this.

```
List<MyObject> FirstList = new List<MyObject>();
// Add items to FirstList.
List<MyObject> SecondList = new List<MyObject>(FirstList.AsReadOnly());
// Is SecondList a read-only collection?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the second list is not read-only, it's still a List generated from an [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) (specifically an [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) here).  The [`.AsReadOnly()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx) method just gives a [`ReadOnlyCollection<MyObject>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx), but we're not modifying *that* collection when messing with the second list.

Instead, you've created a new `List<MyObject>` with its members that *is* editable (via the [`List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx) constructor).  This does the generation like any other `IEnumerable<T>` source that's an `ICollection<T>`, it performs a [`.CopyTo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0efx51xw.aspx) underneath.

In the case of a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` (which implements `ICollection<T>`), it's calling [`.CopyTo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4df7xky9.aspx) on the original `IList<T>` underneath that it was from, so basically what you have is the same as:

```
List<MyObject> FirstList = new List<MyObject>();
// Add items to FirstList.
List<MyObject> SecondList = new List<MyObject>(FirstList);
```

....as far as the second list is concerned.  In other cases where the `IEnumerable<T>` passed to the constructor is *not* a `ICollection<T>`, it would iterate over the collection and [`.Add()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx) each member instead...but it would still have no impact on the mutability of the new list and its members.